# Adjusting for road surface in Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, united-states, streets

I'm building a street network dataset and want to adjust the speed limit of certain segments to account for road surface (paved vs. unpaved).

Are there any guidelines/rules for doing this (e.g. an unpaved road should be set to 5mph)?

Comment: Are you asking *what* the rules should be or *how* to implement them? If what, then no, you get to make the rules or perhaps find some (I've been on unpaved comfortable at 60mph and paved I wouldn't go more than 5mph on), and this question would be off-topic. If you want how, that's another matter and could be done in a couple of ways.

Comment: If you actually state which country you are working in, may be some expert for that country can give you an answer?

Comment: I'm asking _what_ the rules should be and I'm working in Worcester County, MA.

Comment: To avoid your Question being put on hold I recommend that you edit it to make this clear and to address any other clarifications that may arise from potential answerers.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there are no specific rules or guidelines for setting a speed limit based solely on surface type. Road geometry and access points are generally more important factors. Surface type might be a more heavily *weighted* factor in some cases, such as if dust is a concern in a residential area, but I've never seen a case where a specific speed limit was determined on surface type alone. I can think of numerous local (to me) examples of limit ranges on unpaved roads anywhere from 5mph to 50mph - even in the same governing body jurisdiction.

There are a couple of studies I found in a quick search regarding both what to set the speed limit at on an unpaved road and the effectiveness of doing so:

- [Developing Standards and Guidelines for Establishing Speed Limits on
  Unpaved Roads](http://docs.trb.org/prp/12-1520.pdf) (out of Wyoming)
- [Speed Limit-RElated Issues on Gravel Roads](http://ntl.bts.gov/lib/31000/31500/31562/KSU065_Final.pdf) (out of Kansas)

You might also contact the local county streets/traffic department where you are working.